# Python3 Converting Non-English Chars to English Chars

Tags: string, python-3.x, utf-8, char, non-english

I have a text file, I read file and after some operation I put these lines into another file. But input file has some Turkish chars such as "İ,Ö,Ü,Ş,Ç,Ğ". I want these chars to be converted to English chars because when I open the files in UTF-8 encoding, these chars are not shown. My code is below:

```
for i in range (len(singleLine)):
        if singleLine[i] == "İ":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i+1],"I")
        if singleLine[i] == "Ü":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i + 1], "U")
        if singleLine[i] == "Ö":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i + 1], "O")
        if singleLine[i] == "Ç":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i + 1], "C")
        if singleLine[i] == "Ş":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i + 1], "S")
        if singleLine[i] == "Ğ":
            singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i + 1], "G")
    return singleLine
```

But the code does not recognize these Turkish chars in Input file and putting them into outputfile without any operation.

What is the way to recognize these chars? Is there any special way for ASCII code based search or something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in the comment: [answer for switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881320/1261764)

I used that method as:

```
choices = {"İ":"I", "ş" : "s"...}
        singleLine = singleLine.replace(singleLine[i:i+1],choices.get(singleLine[i],singleLine[i]))
```

and it is solved.

Answer (score 7):

`str` instances are immutable so `str.replace()` does not operate in-place but instead returns the result.

But [don't do things the hard way](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode).

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode('İ,Ö,Ü,Ş,Ç,Ğ')
'I,O,U,S,C,G'
```

Note: This is not a script library, but it can be only used over the command-line interface.

Comment: thanks. I solved that like in my post below + thanks to your first sentence comment.

Comment: I find this solution much more feasible than the accepted answer.

Comment: Is the first unicode is the string? Could you please elaborate the answer better.